# PLC: If Then Else inside Function Block

Tags: plc

I'm trying to learn by programming for a Bosch/Rexroth MLC. I wrote this sequence, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to do things.

Pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
wRunningCount=300
wStandstillCount=150
wCount
zeroSpeed
IF zeroSpeed THEN
    wCount=wStandstillCount
ELSE
    wCount=wRunningCount
FI
```

But I want to move this functionality into function blocks. (Already have a TON that will receive the wCount)

Right now I have:

```
                  __MOVE____
       zeroSpeed-|EN    ENO|-
wStandStillCount-|_________|-wCount


                  __MOVE___
      zeroSpeed-o|EN    ENO|-
   wRunningCount-|_________|-wCount
```

Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: What is wrong with your pseudo code? Why dont you use Structured Text that will look almost the same?

Answer (score 1):

depending on how you want to initialize your variables you can do this

[image]

Otherwise there is not better way to do it then you are right now.

Answer (score 1):

Most 61131 implementations will have a "SEL" block that should do this fairly nicely...

```
            __SEL__
zerospeed  |G     Q|wCount
           |       |
wrunning   |IN0    |
           |       |
wstandstill|IN1    |
           |_______|
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the ton block in ST? The rest of your code looks pretty good.

TON_0(enable:=TRUE, PT:=T#1s);

IF TON_0.Q THEN //if timer done

```
//do stuff

TON_0(enable:=FALSE); //reset timer
```

END_IF